# What's the meaning of ヌき所 in this sentence?

Tags: translation, meaning

このシーンは**ヌき所**だな.

Does "This scene is gold, ain't it." work?

Many thanks in advance, sensei-tachi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I guessed the context correctly, jisho.org explains this meaning of 抜く as the **14th** definition:

> #### 抜く
>
> 14. to masturbate (of a male); to ejaculate (while masturbating)

所 just refers to "point" within a video clip.